# Advanced custom multilingual url handling / Role & membership LoginUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, myprettycms

I'm working on a custom FriendlyURL analyzer for my cms (myprettycms.codeplex.com).
The system is multilingual:

- http://www.mydomain.com/en-us/friendly/url/friendly_url_page.htm
- http://www.mydomain.com/fr-fr/friendly/url/friendly_url_page.htm

If you look in the file :

https://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19148#457568

it's the base class of 2 controllers. One is public and the other private.
The difference between 2 code is Authorize decoration in the private one.

The login url depends on the language of the page you are trying to access.

If I'm on an English page like:

http://www.mydomain.com/en-us/products/priduct_list.htm

and if this page is private (the controller is set to `DynaContentPrivateController`) and if I'm not authenticated, the system will redirect my demand to the `LoginURL` defined in the `web.config`.

At this time, it's set to "`~/logon`"

I would have something like "`~/{0}/logon`" and know in witch part of the code I can override a code to replace `{0}` with the **language of the page I was looking for**.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution...

I kept the web.config setting :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

[Web.Config in codeplex](http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19221#457307)

In the RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LogOn",
    url: "LogOn/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "LogOn", action = "SelectLanguage" }
);
```

And in the languages routes loop in RouteConfig.cs

```
foreach (var l in Languages)
{
    ...
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LogOn" + l.Name.ToUpper(),
    url: l.Description + "/logon/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "LogOn", action = "Index", language = l.Description }
    );
    ...
}
```

[The routeconfig.cs in codeplex](http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19221#457313)

In the controller base

```
public string URLReferLanguage
{
    get
    {
        string toReturn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLanguage"];
        string language = string.Empty;
        string[] tLanguages = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Languages"].Split(',');
        string urlReferrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
        if (urlReferrer != null)
        {
            if (urlReferrer.Length > 5)
            {
                language = urlReferrer.Substring(1, 5).ToLower();
                if (tLanguages.Contains(language))
                {
                    toReturn = language;
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

[_Controller_Base in codeplex](http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19221#457022)

In the LogOn Controller in Security Layer

```
public ActionResult SelectLanguage()
{
    return Redirect(string.Format("/{0}{1}", base.URLReferLanguage, Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
}

/// <summary>
/// URL: /en-us/LogOn
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string eMethod = eMethodBase + ".Index[GET]";
    using (DataRepositories _dataContext = new DataRepositories())
    {
        base.InitView(
            Resources.View_LogOn_PageTitle,
            string.Empty,
            specificCssCollection,
            specificJSCollection,
            dynamicJSCollection,
            specificJqueryJSCollection,
            jsVariables,
            externalCSS,
            Meta,
            _dataContext,
            false,
            base.RequestLanguage,
            false
        );
    }
    string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        ContentData.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }
    return View(ContentData);
}
```

[The LogOn controller in codeplex](http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19221#457242)

So, when a user is redirected to LoginForm by standard role and membership (my Provider inherit standard one), controller analyse UrlRefer and add language to address and redirect to it.